# Python Dates - Converting None to Null

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am moving data from a Mysql DB to PostgresDB using Python. My Code looks like below -

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='aaa' user='aaa' host='localhost' password='aaa' ")
curp = conn.cursor()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="root" , unix_socket='/var/mysql/mysql.sock', port=3306 )

cur.execute('select * from aaa_pledge')
list = cur.fetchall()
for l in list:
    print l
    for i in range(len(l)):
        print i, l[i]
    qry = "insert into aaa_pledge values ('%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,%s,'%s',%s,%s,%s,%s,'%s')" %(  l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5], l[6], str(l[7]) , l[8], l[9], l[10], l[11] )
    print qry
    res = curp.execute( qry)
    print res
curp.execute( "commit")
curp.close()
cur.execute( "commit")
cur.close()
```

The code runs fine for ***valid dates*** and executes as below -

```
('500055', 'NEERAJ SINGAL', datetime.date(2014, 12, 4), 'NEERAJ SINGAL', Decimal('57221712.00'), Decimal('25.2600000'), 'INVOCATION', datetime.date(2014, 12, 4), Decimal('0E-7'), Decimal('0E-7'), Decimal('0E-7'), '-')
0 500055
1 NEERAJ SINGAL
2 2014-12-04
3 NEERAJ SINGAL
4 57221712.00
5 25.2600000
6 INVOCATION
***7 2014-12-04***
8 0E-7
9 0E-7
10 0E-7
11 -
insert into aaa_pledge values ('500055','NEERAJ SINGAL','2014-12-04','NEERAJ SINGAL',57221712.00,25.2600000,'INVOCATION','2014-12-04',0E-7,0E-7,0E-7,'-')
```

But when the source has nulls, in the tuple we get a None

```
('500055', 'NEERAJ SINGAL', datetime.date(2014, 11, 26), 'NEERAJ SINGAL', Decimal('57394244.00'), Decimal('25.3300000'), 'INVOCATION', ***None,*** Decimal('0E-7'), Decimal('0E-7'), Decimal('0E-7'), '-')
0 500055
1 NEERAJ SINGAL
2 2014-11-26
3 NEERAJ SINGAL
4 57394244.00
5 25.3300000
6 INVOCATION
***7 None***
8 0E-7
9 0E-7
10 0E-7
11 -
insert into aaa_pledge values ('500055','NEERAJ SINGAL','2014-11-26','NEERAJ SINGAL',57394244.00,25.3300000,'INVOCATION','None',0E-7,0E-7,0E-7,'-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pransfer_data.py", line 27, in <module>
    res = curp.execute( qry)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type date: "None"
LINE 1: ...EERAJ SINGAL',57394244.00,25.3300000,'INVOCATION','None',0E-...
```

I read some notes about using %s rather than '%s' and also about using str(l[7]). However in each case if the code runs fine for valid dates, it fails for invalid ones and vice versa. I am going to face this problem for other integer values also.

Is there a way to

1. Auto convert None to null and
2. Change '%s' for valid dates to %s for null dates as and when required.

PS - I have lot of dates and numeric cols where this is going to be required. I will not be able to do a if then else for each of the columns.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Why not do l[7] = '' if l[7] is None else l[7]

Comment: That will give me '' which will be rejected by the database. I need something like this insert into table (dt1) values ('2015-01-01') when its not None and insert into table (dt1) values ( null ) when the date is None.. The 2 quotes are interpreted as invalid date

Comment: ('' if l[7] is None else l[7])
insert into bse_pledge values ('500055','NEERAJ SINGAL','2014-11-26','NEERAJ SINGAL',57394244.00,25.3300000,'INVOCATION','',0E-7,0E-7,0E-7,'-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pransfer_data.py", line 27, in <module>
    res = curp.execute( qry)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
LINE 1: ...EERAJ SINGAL',57394244.00,25.3300000,'INVOCATION','',0E-7,0E...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is to invoke the [parameterized form](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#execute) of the psycopg2's `cursor.execute` method - pass in the query (with `%s` placeholders, **without** interpolating it right away) as a string for the first parameter of `execute`, and then pass in a tuple containing your parameter values as the second parameter.  Something like:

```
insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
cursor.execute(insertQuery, (1, 'Alice', datetime.date(2014, 12, 4)))
```

Consider the following silly test table:

```
rchang=> \d foo
                Table "public.foo"
 Column |            Type             | Modifiers
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id     | integer                     |
 name   | text                        |
 ts     | timestamp without time zone |
```

With the following Python code performing insertions:

```
insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'

conn = psycopg2.connect(connString)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(insertQuery, (1, 'Alice', datetime.date(2014, 12, 4)))
cursor.execute(insertQuery, (2, 'Bob', None))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Then we get the following result in the database:

```
rchang=> select * from foo;
 id | name  |         ts      
----+-------+---------------------
  1 | Alice | 2014-12-04 00:00:00
  2 | Bob   |
(2 rows)
```

Note that when you use the parameterized version, `None` gets properly inserted as a null value into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need a NULLIF and a CAST:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(bar date);

INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES('2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO  foo(bar) VALUES('None');   -- fails

INSERT INTO  foo(bar) VALUES(CAST(NULLIF('None', 'None') AS DATE)); -- works fine
INSERT INTO  foo(bar) VALUES(CAST(NULLIF('2015-01-01', 'None') AS DATE)); -- works fine as well
```